# Define ID of clicked element and pass it through to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, binding

I want to pass variable "pageSetUp" from the on click event go through to function x and I keep going in circles.. I'm still a bit of noob when it comes to js. I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var pageSetUp = $(this).attr("ID");  
});

function x(pageSetUp){
        if(pageSetUp == page1){             
            //do something
        }
        else if(pageSetUp == page2){
            //do something else
        }else{

        }                   
});

x();
```

Comment: ....you're...not calling `x` from your handler....?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need call x with desired parameter.:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var pageSetUp = $(this).attr("ID");
    x(pageSetUp);
});

function x(pageSetUp){
        if(pageSetUp == page1){             
            //do something
        }
        else if(pageSetUp == page2){
            //do something else
        }else{

        }                   
};
```